How can I carry a monoidal structure over an equivalence of $\infty$-categories?
This is basically the higher categorical version of this question, but with the added difficulty of dealing with higher coherences.
So, a symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category is defined as a coCartesian fibration
$$
\newcommand{\Ccat}{\mathcal{C}} \newcommand{\Dcat}{\mathcal{D}} \newcommand{\Fin}{\text{Fin}} \Ccat^{\otimes} \to N(\Fin_\ast)
$$
satisfying the Segal condition; the fiber over $\left< 1 \right> \in N(\Fin_\ast)$, denoted $\Ccat : = \Ccat^{\otimes}_{\left< 1 \right>}$, is called the underlying category.
Here the notion of coCartesian fibration is of model-theoretic nature, as it is defined as an inner fibration solving certain lifting problems in a specific way. Consider now another $\infty$-category $\Dcat$ and an equivalence $f: \Dcat \xrightarrow{\simeq} \Ccat$, i.e. an invertible morphism in the $\infty$-category $\text{Cat}_{\infty}$; this is something of homotopic-theoretic nature.
Question. Is it possible to carry the symmetric monoidal structure from $\Ccat$ to $\Dcat$ trough the equivalence $f$ in a natural way, and if yes, how? Intuitively this should be possible, as in the $1$-categorical world; this is also suggested by Lurie in Remark 3.6.5 in DAG III.
I should also mention that, while I believe that one can make sense of the notion of coCartesian fibration by rephrasing it internally in $\text{Cat}_{\infty}$ (maybe rephrasing the notion of cocartesian lifts and inner fibrations), and I'd be glad to hear such a story, I'm particularly interested in hearing the solution to this problem as Lurie seem to have intendeded it in the remark cited above, so using the usual notion of coCartesian fibration and working in simplicial sets. Thanks!

A symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category is a cocartesian fibration $\mathcal{C}^\otimes \to N\mathrm{Fin}_*$ which satisfies the Segal condition.

@BenSteffan good catch; I have fixed it now.

I think this is trickier than it sounds even for 1-categories. (Presumably you intend to define $\otimes$ in $\mathcal{D}$ by applying $f$, then $\otimes$ in $\mathcal{C}$, and some chosen quasi-inverse of $f$. How do you verify the axioms after defining the transported operations?)

I think this might be too cheeky an answer, but it seems the monoidal structure on $\mathcal{D}$ is witnessed by $\mathcal{C}^\otimes \to \mathrm{Fin}_*$.
I'm not sure if Lurie defines what it means precisely for $\mathcal{C}$ to admit a particular symmetric monoidal structure but it seems the only reasonable definition would be that there is some cocartesian fibration $\mathcal{C}^\otimes \to \mathrm{Fin}_*$ satisfying the Segal condition such that $\mathcal{C}^\otimes_{\langle 1 \rangle}$ is equivalent to $\mathcal{C}$. (Equivalently, we can ask that the homotopy fiber of $\mathcal{C}^\otimes \to \mathrm{Fin}_*$ be $\mathcal{C}$). This is certainly in line with how other definitions in higher category theory work. For instance, the Segal conditions we use to define symmetric monoidal $\infty$-categories require only that $\mathcal{C}_{\langle n \rangle}^\otimes$ be equivalent to $(\mathcal{C}_{\langle 1 \rangle}^\otimes)^n$, not that the relevant simplicial sets presenting these strict limits be isomorphic.
The only alternative (which you seem to have in mind) is that we require the strict fiber $\mathcal{C}^\otimes_{\langle 1 \rangle}$ computed in simplicial sets be isomorphic to $\mathcal{C}$, so then there is some work necessary to shift $\mathcal{C}^\otimes \to \mathrm{Fin}_*$ to change this strict fiber. This is really a calculation of quasicategories rather than $(\infty,1)$-categories, but it is certainly possible. I'm not sure how useful such a maneuver is, but I've given a brief sketch below.
For instance, we can straighten $\mathcal{C}^\otimes$ to a functor to $\mathrm{Cat}$ modeled as in e.g., Cisinski and Nguyen's paper (so that we can arrange the strict pullback be isomorphic to the original map of simplicial sets). We can then take advantage of the fact that $\{0\} \times \mathrm{Fin}_* \bigsqcup_{\{0\} \times \mathrm{Sk}_0(\mathrm{Fin}_*)} J \times \mathrm{Sk}_0(\mathrm{Fin}_*) \to J \times \mathrm{Fin}_*$ is anodyne where $J$ is the nerve of the walking isomorphism $\{0 \cong 1\}$. We use the fact that $\mathrm{Cat}$ is a quasicategory to choose a new functor $\mathrm{Fin}_* \to \mathrm{Cat}$ equivalent to $\mathrm{Str}(\mathcal{C}^\otimes \to \mathrm{Fin}_*)$ but with the strict value at $\langle 1 \rangle$ being given by $\mathcal{D}$ instead of $\mathcal{C}$.

Not sure either whether Lurie defines what it means for $\mathcal{C}$ to admit  particular symmetric monoidal structure, but at least the discussion of cartesian symmetric monoidal structures seems to suggest that this is to be understood up to equivalence: A cartesian symmetric monoidal structure is essentially a symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category $\mathcal{D}^\otimes$ with certain properties and a functor $\mathcal{D}^\otimes \to \mathcal{C}$ restricting to an equivalence $\mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ (cf. HA2.4.1.1).

@danielgratzer indeed, my confusion arose because I was considering $\mathcal{C}_{\left< 1 \right>}^{\otimes}$ to be strictly isomorphic to $\mathcal{C}$. The second part of the answer went a bit over my head, but I guess that morally it means that by straightening, we can levelwise compose the functor with a choice of equivalence $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ and quasi-inverse, and then by unstraightening back I get an actual coCartesian fibration. Is this correct? Thanks for the answer!

@Frusciante yes exactly, though of course this argument depends heavily on specific models of various things (such as Cat) since it's not an equivalence invariant property
